# How to download files from Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a folder named `output` inside a bucket named `BucketA`. I have a list of files in `output` folder. How do I download them to my local machine using AWS Java SDK ?

Below is my code:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        File localFile = new File("/home/abc/Desktop/AmazonS3/");
        s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucketA", "/bucketA/output/"), localFile);
```

And I got the error:

```
AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist.
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that S3 is not a filesystem, but it is an [object store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_storage).  There's a huge difference between the two, one being that directory-style activities simply won't work.

Suppose you have an S3 bucket with two objects in it:

```
/path/to/file1.txt
/path/to/file2.txt
```

When working with these objects you can't simply refer to `/path/to/` like you can when working with files in a filesystem directory.  That's because `/path/to/` is not a directory but just part of a key in a very large hash table. This is why the error message indicates an issue with a *key*. These are not filename paths but keys to objects within the object store.

In order to copy all the files in a location like `/path/to/` you need to perform it in multiple steps.  First, you need to get a listing of all the objects whose keys begin with `/path/to`, then you need to loop through each individual object and copy them one by one.

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539475/download-a-large-number-of-files-using-the-java-sdk-for-amazon-s3-bucket) with an answer that shows how to download multiple files from S3 using Java.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question was asked longtime ago, but still this answer might help some one.

You might want to use something like this to download objects from S3

```
 new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("bucketName").withDelimiter("delimiter").withPrefix("path/to/image/");
```

as mentioned in the [S3 doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html)

**delimiter** be *"/"* and **prefix** be your *"folder like structure"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the predefined classes for upload directory and download directory

**For Download**

```
MultipleFileDownload xfer = xfer_mgr.downloadDirectory(
    bucketName, key, new File("C:\\Users\\miracle\\Deskto\\Downloads"));
```

**For Upload**

```
MultipleFileUpload xfer = xfer_mgr.uploadDirectory(bucketName, key,Dir,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the bucket (in this case "bucketA") does not contain a file with the name you specified (in this case "/bucketA/output/").

When you specify the key, do not include the bucket name in the key. S3 supports "folders" in the key, which are delimited with "/", so you probably do not want to try to use keys that end with "/".

If your bucket "bucketA" contains a file called "output", you probably want to say

```
new GetObjectRequest("bucketA", "output")
```

If this doesn't work, other things to check:

- Do the credentials you are using have permission to read from the bucket?
- Did you spell all the names correctly?

You might want to use `listObjects("bucketA")` to verify what the bucket actually contains (as seen with the credentials you are using).

Comment: i want the files inside output folder. how should i do it ?